# how to use Interfaces in method of class in java?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api

When I use an interfaces in android how can I return it as a method? For example:

```
public interface Status {
    public void Oncheck(boolean Ok);
}
```

and

```
   public boolean Login(String Username, String Password)
{
    apic.Execute_Bool(
            "/Login_Small?username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "", new Status() {
                @Override
                public void Oncheck(boolean Ok) {
                    return ;
                }
            });
}
```

and

```
 public void Execute_Bool(String Url,final Status callback)
{
    Api_HttpClient.get(Url, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode==200)
            callback.Oncheck(true);
            else callback.Oncheck(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            callback.Oncheck(false);
        }
    });
}
```

when i use Login(username,password) no bool returned.
but when use

```
     apic.Execute_Bool(
        "/Login_Small?username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "", new Status() {
            @Override
            public void Oncheck(boolean Ok) {
                return ;
            }
        });
```

in activity it is work.
what can i do to set it in methid?

Comment: Note you can replace a sequence like `if (statusCode==200)
            callback.Oncheck(true);
            else callback.Oncheck(false)` with a simple `callback.Oncheck(statusCode==200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your login method method has no return statement, I doubt that this code even compiles like this.
Since you're already making an asynchronous http call, you can't really get the login method to return synchronously. Your code will execute in the following order:

```
1: Login method is invoked
2: apic.Execute_Bool is invoked
3: Api_HttpClient.get is invoked
4: Api_HttpClient.get returns
5: apic.Execute_Bool returns
6: Login returns
?: Status.Oncheck is invoked (Could be called at any time, but most likely after Login has returned)
```

There are 2 ways of tackling this problem:
you could refactor your code so that the method which calls Login doesn't need a return value and write another method which will then be called from Oncheck method.
Or you could look for a synchronous way of making that http request, you'd have to check the documentation for that one.
By the way, in java the only names that start with an uppercase letter are classnames. Methods and variables start with a lowercase use camelCase (apic.executeBool).